# How to find schemaType of Mongoose Array element

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm trying to retrieve the schema type from the below code.

Please help me to get the schema type as String Array.

I have the schema as below:

```
export const meetingSchema = new Schema({
  MT_meetingType: String,
  MT_meetingFormat: String, 
  MT_meetingFormatSecond: String,
  MT_meetingFormatSecondInput:  String, 
  MT_meetingFormatInput: String,`enter code here`
  MT_meetingNumber: String,
  MT_location: String,
  MT_requestedBy: [String], })
```

**And I'm iterating all elements in the schema as below:**

```
 const keys = Object.keys(Meeting.schema.paths);



     for (const index in keys) { 
            console.log('keys index ', keys[index], typeof keys[index]);
        }
```

But when I try to retrieve the type of `MT_requestedBy` it's coming as String instead of **`[String]`**,

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

**Create your schema something like this:**

```
export const meetingSchema = new Schema({
  MT_meetingType: { type: String },
  MT_meetingFormat: { type: String }, 
  MT_meetingFormatSecond: { type: String },
  MT_meetingFormatSecondInput:  { type: String }, 
  MT_meetingFormatInput: { type: String },
  MT_meetingNumber: { type: String },
  MT_location: { type: String },
  MT_requestedBy: [{ type: String }]
 });
```

Now do what you are doing.
**Hope it will help you.**